# JSON performance tips. Drupal backend and IONIC Frontend

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I am creating a hybrid app (IONIC + AngularJS). Using Drupal as my Backend. I am using Drupal services and getting the JSON data.

I would like to improve the speed/performance of getting the data. Most of the data will be images. 

 On the first page, i just want a list of the user's firstnames. When you click on a name you get the details page for that user. This page contains a lot of images.

What is the best way of doing this? 
If my list contains a 100 people with profile pictures. I don't want to download all this information. Just the information of the person that was selected from the list. Is this possible? Is this a good idea? I am sorry if this is dumb questions. I am a beginner.

Do you have a better suggestion on how to do this?
Thanks in advance

JSON
    [{"firstName":"John", "Image1":"John.jpg", "Image2":"John2.jpg", "Image3":"John3.jpg"},
{"firstName":"Jane", "Image1":"Jane.jpg", "Image2":"Jane2.jpg", "Image3":"Jane3.jpg"},
{"firstName":"Sam", "Image1":"Sam.jpg", "Image2":"Sam2.jpg", "Image3":"Sam3.jpg"}]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are few links you might want to go through for performance

- https://www.sitepoint.com/5-ionic-app-development-tips-tricks/
- http://julienrenaux.fr/2015/08/24/ultimate-angularjs-and-ionic-performance-cheat-sheet/
- http://www.gajotres.net/speed-up-your-ionic-application-using-these-techniques/

Regards.